# Is the removal of Bitcoin checkpoints considered a hard-fork?

Tags: blockchain-fork, consensus, checkpoints, assume-valid

The [value](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/e4e201dfd9a9dbd8e22cac688dbbde16234cd937/src/validation.h#L67) of `DEFAULT_CHECKPOINTS_ENABLED` is `true` and changing it will allow nodes **using the default settings** to accept blocks that would be currently rejected during a potential reorg. Is this change considered a hard-fork, or only changes to clearly enforced consensus rules can qualify as such?

Comment: That's a bit of a stretch. Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/75735/5406

Answer (score 2):

A hard fork is defined as a relaxation of the consensus rules. (In contrast a soft fork is defined as a restriction of the consensus rules.) Changing the consensus rules to ignore checkpoints by default (assuming the reference client Bitcoin Core defines the consensus rules) would be a relaxation of the consensus rules and hence theoretically a hard fork. However, in reality the checkpoints that have been defined in Bitcoin Core are many years deep and the probability of a re-org back to these checkpoints is infinitesimally small (zero to a huge number of decimal places). So practically it wouldn't have any impact.

Checkpoints and assumedvalid was discussed at this London BitDevs [Socratic Seminar](https://btctranscripts.com/london-bitcoin-devs/2021-11-02-socratic-seminar-assumeutxo/#assumedvalid-and-checkpoints) in November 2021 on AssumeUTXO.